# multi pattern in sed -n

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I know there are quite a few questions asked on this topic. But I need help in a case basis.When i try to put more than 3 pattern in the option,
i will get the error like that...

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unknown command: `,'
```

i only want to print the words in the brackets..

here is the sed command

```
sed -n '/QUEUE/,/CURDEPTH/,/DESCR/ {
            s/QUEUE(\(.*\))\(.*TYPE(.*)\)/\1/
            s/QUEUE(\(.*\))/\1/
            s/TYPE(.*).*CURDEPTH(\(.*\))/\1/
            s/CURDEPTH(\(.*\))/\1/
            s/TYPE(.*).*DESCR(\(.*\))/\1/
            s/DESCR(\(.*\))/\1/
         p
       }
    ' | awk '{ if ((NR %2) == 0) { printf("%s\n", $0) } else { printf("%s", $0) } }'
```

and the output...

```
test.msg.queue   0)                             DESCR(TQ : 001
```

thanks...

sample output

```
1 : dis q(test.msg.queue) CURDEPTH DESCR
AMQ0086: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(test.msg.queue)                 TYPE(QLOCAL)
   CURDEPTH(0)                             DESCR(TQ : 001)
```

Comment: it would help if you add few sample lines (say 3-5) and complete expected output for the sample - this would help add clarity about your question and also helps in testing solutions before answering.. from what you've posted, it looks like you need `/QUEUE\|CURDEPTH\|DESCR/`

Comment: What "range" is `/QUEUE/,/CURDEPTH/,/DESCR/` supposed to refer to? Every line starting with one containing `QUEUE`, and ending ... when? Can you describe what your *aiming* to achieve?

Comment: thanks for help ghoti ,i am aim for get the text out of brackets.. Sundeep solution seem work, but output still same with "test.msg.queue   0)                             DESCR(TQ : 001", i think i help to check X_X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong expectation.  You are asking about the "address" portion of a `sed` instruction, which specifies on which lines `sed` should apply the following command. `sed` does not accept a list of addresses there.  It accepts either a single address (often, but not always, a regex), or an address *range*, expressed as a comma-separated start and end address.  There is no address form that accepts a comma-delimited list of three or more regexes.

But `sed` doesn't need that; you're making things too complicated.  Regexes already naturally provide for matching a list of separate options.  That's what the `|` operator is for:

```
sed -n '/QUEUE\|CURDEPTH\|DESCR/ {
            s/QUEUE(\(.*\))\(.*TYPE(.*)\)/\1/
```

...